# inserting Javascript variable into database through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

```
<script>
var school_address = "<?php echo $school_address; ?>";
L.esri.Geocoding.geocode().text(school_address).run((err, results, response) => {
console.log(results.results[0].latlng);
// retrieve latitude, longitude from related response
const { lat, lng } = results.results[0].latlng;
};  


$(document).ready(function()){
    $.post('coordinate.php', results.results[0].latlng )
    .done(function(response) {
    alert("Data Loaded: " + response);
});

</script>
```

I am trying to geocode a physical address and convert to coordinate, then insert them into database, but the code is not working. I am not sure if my code had any syntax error or if I had done sth wrong. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We don't have enough to know what's wrong. You could at a '.error(function(error)' to display the error that is generated. Also it's the coordinate.php file that is most important because it's that code that inserts it into the db.

Comment: I guess your `run()` function is an async call.
So its not safe that when the `document.ready` function is running that your lat lng is filled with infos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    var school_address = "<?php echo $school_address; ?>";
    L.esri.Geocoding.geocode().text(school_address).run((err, results, response) => {
        console.log(results.results[0].latlng);
        const {lat, lng} = results.results[0].latlng;
    });


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.post('coordinate.php', results.results[0].latlng)
            .done(function (response) {
                alert("Data Loaded: " + response);
            });
    })
</script>
```

Try this.
Seems to me that you forgot some curly braces after you initiated a callback function. I'm very certain that it fires. Can't find any other highlighting. You also forgot one of these: ) to close the run function.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're missing braces there bud. Do you not have an IDE or text editor with syntax highlighting?

```
L.esri.Geocoding.geocode().text(school_address).run((err, results, response) => {
console.log(results.results[0].latlng);
// retrieve latitude, longitude from related response
const { lat, lng } = results.results[0].latlng;
};
```

is missing the ); for the .run call, between the closing } and the ;.
You should also be able to see a red issue reported by the developer tools of your browser. Once you've got that figured out, see if the ajax call actually makes it to your webserver.